# dispatcherTimer not restarting

Tags: c#, winui-3, dispatchertimer

I'm implementing a countdown in my app

```
private async void Window_Activated(object sender, WindowActivatedEventArgs args)
{       
  dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
  dispatcherTimer.Tick += dispatcherTimer_Tick;
  dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,1,0);
  dispatcherTimer.Start();     
}

private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
  TimeSpan timeSpan = new TimeSpan(blockTime.Hours, blockTime.Minutes, blockTime.Seconds);

  if (timeSpan != TimeSpan.Zero)
  {
    timeSpan = timeSpan.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
    Countdown_TexBlock.Text = String.Format("{0}:{1}", timeSpan.Hours, timeSpan.Minutes);
    dispatcherTimer.Start();   
  }     
  else
  {
    dispatcherTimer.Stop();
  }
}
```

The code works but only one time
For example I put 15 minutes in the blocktime (the time that the countdown will be running)
after a minute the countdown.text would be  0:14.
So only works after the first minute

Is not supposed to be restarted with dispatcher.start()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code that you posted, I don't see the `blockTime` variable being changed to any other value than it has in the beginning. This means that on every tick of `dispatchTimer` the value of the `timeSpan.Subtract` expression will always evaluate to the same 14 minutes. In your code, that 14 minutes is assigned to a local vaiable that is disposed when the tick is over. This gives the appearance that the `dispatchTimer` has stopped issuing `Tick` when it hasn't.

---

Here's what I ran that works as expected (for testing, I changed the minutes to seconds to make it observable in a reasonable time).

```
public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        // Create the dispatch timer ONCE
        dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += DispatcherTimer_Tick;
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

        // This will restart the timer every
        // time the window is activated
        this.Activated += (sender, e) =>
        {
            startOrRestartDispatchTimer();
        };
    }

    private void startOrRestartDispatchTimer()
    {
        dispatcherTimer.Stop(); // If already running
        blockTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
        Countdown_TexBlock.Text = blockTime.ToString();
        dispatcherTimer.Start();
    }

    private void DispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        if (blockTime > TimeSpan.Zero)
        {
            blockTime = blockTime.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            Countdown_TexBlock.Text = blockTime.ToString();
            if (blockTime == TimeSpan.Zero)
            {
                Countdown_TexBlock.Text = "Done";
                dispatcherTimer.Stop();
            }
        }
    }

    TimeSpan blockTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);

    private DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer;

    // This will restart the timer when the button is clicked.
    private void buttonRestart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) =>
        startOrRestartDispatchTimer();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but I'm still having a problem after a couple of minutes ,  the timer start getting faster (the seconds last less)

Comment: Sorry I missed that! In your original code, the dispatch timer gets a new event _every time_ the window is activated and I copied that more or less. What _should_ happen is the timer gets created (and the event subscribed to) only **once**. I edited the code to show this and will push that commit.

Comment: Plz let me know if there is still any problem. [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/dispatcher-timer-restart.git).

Comment: it's working smoothly, thanks for your help you only not solve my problem you also explained to me.